# (Almost) data loss free memory supported database

Tags: mysql

Is it at all possible? I tried the memory mysql engine but the data is lost after a normal reboot. Is there an engine (or setting) that reads from memory and writes to memory and hdd?

I hear you thinking: why you want a memory engine if you're still using hdd? Well, the write performace isn't the problem, reading is.

Also, i noticed some people running a database on a ramdisk, is this safe? And is it possible to run only a few tables on the ramdisk?

Comment: If you have sufficient memory, then the database should already have all of the content in RAM (either directly via application data cache, or via the OS disk cache). Have you done any performance testing to make sure that you really can't just use a normal disk-backed database?

Comment: Yes, i created indexes. Optimized column attributes and ran mysqltuner.pl.